# Making a Character Hold A Weapon

Tags: rigging, unity

Well I am trying to make a character hold a sword, or a knife but when I rig a hand container for the weapon, mixamo doesn't animate it right for me, sword points to wrong places. I can not use child of constraint since unity does not support constraints. Any idea how can I do it and import it to Unity?

Comment: You can set parent or enable/disable object in Unity in script, that can be triggered by animation state

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.